# Imported alembic from Maya. No lights are working at all besides Sun light?

Tags: light, lighting

I am new to Blender and have been struggling, trying to read online as much as I can to try to solve this but I am stumped.

I had a friend animate a shot for me in Maya. He exported out his scene as an alembic cache and passed that on to me. I imported the .abc into Blender - the animation worked, and I was able to manually set up the shaders and textures again.

However, once I went to start lighting, it seems that no lights are working at all - the scene is just black for the most part. The only light that does work is a Sun light. But point/spot/area - even if I turn up the size and power of the light to insane numbers, nothing is being lit.

The scale of the scene is pretty massive, as the subjects are a spaceship and a planet in space. I tried reducing the scale of the scene to 5% its original size, to see if maybe it was just too large for the lights to catch anything, but even at a smaller size, I was seeing no light.

There's also a random "directionalLight1" in the scene that I did not create, it must've ported over from the .abc.

Here's a link that has my .blend scene and also the original .abc if anyone wants to try importing from scratch:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1I-6OXrT-VAyYe_4-ANUYUOC1mW3aX7lV?usp=sharing

Appreciate any help on this as I am truly stumped! Thank you!

Comment: Hi and welcome. Imported the alembic file at `0.1`, added a point light to the given "Directional Light" empty and it's working fine for cycles and eevee on 2.9  linux, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/akeBJ.jpg  Just make sure to set the light intensity (power) and size to a proper value according (or relative) to your scene scale. BTW: The camera min clipping value is set to 5, which is pretty high, I would suggest turning that down to a low value like `0.1`, might cause rendering problems later on.

Comment: Thank you @brockmann - it seems I underestimated just how large the scene was! I had set the power of the light to 500,000 W previously. But going into MW as in your screenshot, I started seeing the light influence. Thanks very much!